# I get this error Application Error in Django Heroku HOW to solve it?

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
my gunicorn :  web: gunicorn https://serene-atoll-07314.herokuapp.com/ --log-file -


2021-08-16T11:29:39.421911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn learning_logs.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-08-16T11:29:41.369052+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-08-16T11:29:41.369655+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:41765 (4)
2021-08-16T11:29:41.369730+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-08-16T11:29:41.373634+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377020+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377021+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377022+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377022+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377022+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377023+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377023+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377024+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377024+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377024+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377025+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377025+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377025+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377025+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377025+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377026+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377026+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377026+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377026+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.wsgi'
2021-08-16T11:29:41.377092+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-08-16T11:29:41.407065+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-08-16T11:29:41.407153+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:41 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-08-16T11:29:41.482746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-08-16T11:29:41.607641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-16T11:29:41.614239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-16T11:29:44.979775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn learning_logs.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-08-16T11:29:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-08-16T11:29:47.015811+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-08-16T11:29:47.016196+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:41394 (4)
2021-08-16T11:29:47.016246+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-08-16T11:29:47.019350+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022390+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022394+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022396+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022401+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022402+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022402+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022403+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022403+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022404+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022404+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022404+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022404+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022405+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022405+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022405+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022406+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022406+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022406+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022406+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022407+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022407+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022407+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'learning_logs.wsgi'
2021-08-16T11:29:47.022464+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-08-16T11:29:47.045340+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-08-16T11:29:47.045372+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-16 11:29:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-08-16T11:29:47.103003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-08-16T11:29:47.486086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check your file structure.
In your learning_logs directory look for the file **wsgi.py** that contains the following code (here I assume your settings.py file is located to learning_logs.settings):

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "learning_logs.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```